# Prolog Count Occurrences in 2 lists

Tags: list, recursion, count, prolog

- I want to compare 2 list, for each element.
- Count the number of equal elements.

Im so close, please help me:

```
%list vs list%
count2([],[],0).
count2([H1|T1],[H2|T2],S):-
    count(H1,[H2|T2],N),
    count2(T1,[H2|T2],M),
    S is N+M.

%1 element vs 1 list%
count(_, [], 0).
count(X, [X | T], N) :-
  !, count(X, T, N1),
  N is N1 + 1.
count(X, [_ | T], N) :-
  count(X, T, N).

A test:
1 ?- count2([2],[1,2,3],S).
false.
```

Trace:

```
2 ?- count2([2],[1,2,3],S).

   Redo: (5) read_history(h, '!h', [trace, end_of_file], '~! ?- ', _G154, _G155) ? creep
Correct to: "count2([2],[1,2,3],S)"? 
Please answer 'y' or 'n'? yes
   Call: (7) count2([2], [1, 2, 3], _G306) ? creep
   Call: (8) count(2, [1, 2, 3], _G631) ? creep
   Call: (9) count(2, [2, 3], _G631) ? creep
   Call: (10) count(2, [3], _G631) ? creep
   Call: (11) count(2, [], _G631) ? creep
   Exit: (11) count(2, [], 0) ? creep
   Exit: (10) count(2, [3], 0) ? creep
   Call: (10) _G632 is 0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 1 is 0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) count(2, [2, 3], 1) ? creep
   Exit: (8) count(2, [1, 2, 3], 1) ? creep
   Call: (8) count2([], [1, 2, 3], _G637) ? creep
   Fail: (8) count2([], [1, 2, 3], _G637) ? creep
   Redo: (11) count(2, [], _G631) ? creep
   Fail: (11) count(2, [], _G631) ? creep
   Fail: (10) count(2, [3], _G631) ? creep
   Fail: (9) count(2, [2, 3], _G631) ? creep
   Fail: (8) count(2, [1, 2, 3], _G631) ? creep
   Fail: (7) count2([2], [1, 2, 3], _G306) ? creep
false.
```

(Returns the solution, but I have a problem with recursion)

Requested output #1:

```
?- count2([2],[1,2,3],S).
S = 1.
```

(2 is 1 time in the list).

Requested output #2:

```
?- count2([1,2],[1,2,3],S).
S = 2
```

(1 is 1 time in the list).
(2 is 1 time in the list).
Total = 2 equal elements.

Comment: What is not working? Please provide a sample query with the output you get and the requested output...

Comment: Ok editing, one moment

Comment: What are the assumptions about the lists be? What should the query `count2([1,2], [3,2,1], S).` result in?

Comment: (1 is 1 time in the list). (2 is 1 time in the list). Total = 2 equal elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to recurse on elements of the main list and check whether each element is a member of your test list:

```
count(_, [], 0).
count(Xs, [H|T], C) :-
    (   member(H, Xs)
    ->  C #= C1 + 1
    ;   C1 = C
    ),
    count(Xs, T, C1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
count2([],[_|_],0).
count2([H1|T1],[H2|T2],S):-
    count(H1,[H2|T2],N),
    count2(T1,[H2|T2],M),
    S is N+M.


count(_, [], 0).
count(X, [X | T], N) :-
  !, count(X, T, N1),
  N is N1 + 1.
count(X, [_ | T], N) :-
  count(X, T, N).
```

[Solved!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYyKe.jpg)

Comment: There's no need fo `[H2|T2]`. You can just call it `L`.